# Find a complex number that satisfies the equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Find one complex value

of $x$ that satisfies the equation

$\sqrt{3}\cdot x^7+x^4 +2=0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have thoughts or have tried anything? Regards

Comment: Yikes ! That's an ugly equation. Are you sure you did copy correctly the exponents and all the stuff?

Comment: Hint - see if $x = \cos t + i \sin t$ leads to at least one (or two) solutions.  Note $x^r = \cos (rt) + i \sin (rt)$ in such case.

Answer (score 1):

Try nice numbers: You can verify that $x=\exp(j\frac{\pi}{6})$ is a solution. Or cheat like I did: Let the computer solve it, find a solution with norm roughly $1$, calculate its phase, divide that by $\pi$, see if you get a nice number, substitute and verify.

Another nice solution is $\exp(-j\frac{\pi}{6})$. The other $5$ solutions are roughly:

$-1.105404520811946$

$0.303994353126236+i1.0274651948613658$

$0.303994353126236-i1.0274651948613658$

$-0.6173174864699502-i0.7271645552171053$

$-0.6173174864699502+i0.7271645552171053$